# Applying for USA permanent residency during 10 year ban

Tags: usa, overstaying, spouses, visa-bans, us-permanent-residents

I am an American and my husband overstayed his tourist visa in the U.S. We are married and living out of the country. He has an approved I-130. Can he still receive a green card during his 10 year ban or will we be rejected and told to wait until after his ban? Thanks

Comment: He can be granted a waiver based on extreme hardship circumstances. In your case the chances are virtually zero. Forget it and wait till the ten years are over.

Comment: The 10 year ban ends in 7 months. I'm wondering if I should go ahead and start the nvc process and file everything the day after the ban.

Comment: Your application cannot be accepted until after the ban, sorry.